# Flash looping animation while pressed a key

Tags: flash, animation, movieclip

1st movieclip of pipe contains 3 frames "normal", "right" and "left" and a movieclip of flame on a different layer.
When I press right or left there should be animation of flame, which is a movieclip with 4 frames inside it. THE PROBLEM IS I get a **one time** animation and then flame's animation is stopping. I want to flame movieclip to continue animate when my key is pressed, like fire is burning.

```
var speedHoriz:Number = 0;
function animPig(evt:Event):void{
    pipe.x += speedHoriz;
}
pipe.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animPig);

function keyDownHandler (evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(evt.keyCode==37) {
        speedHoriz -= .1;       
        pipe.gotoAndStop("left");
    } else if(evt.keyCode==39) {
        speedHoriz += .1;
        pipe.gotoAndStop("right");
    }
}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyUpHandler (evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
    pipe.gotoAndStop("normal");
}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
```

[SWF](http://megaswf.com/s/2678462)

Comment: @lgogogo,  if you put your MovieClip 'flame' on your scene, does this one work correctly?

Comment: Its looping yes. But I need to use it with the pipe.

Comment: @lgogogo, if this MovieClip works on the scene, there will be no reason for him to not work in another MovieClip. Flame is only composed of four frames (not any code)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! The man from other forum helped me :D!
You need to reset you keyboard polling.

```
function keyDownHandler (evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
if(evt.keyCode==37) {
    speedHoriz -= .1;       
    keyCode==evt.keyCode?null:pipe.gotoAndStop("left");

} else if(evt.keyCode==39) {
    speedHoriz += .1;
    keyCode==evt.keyCode?null:pipe.gotoAndStop("right");
}
keyCode=evt.keyCode;
}
```